# What is the source of this error org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: collection was processed twice by flush() and how to prevent it?

Tags: hibernate, search

I'm getting this kind of error that said.

> org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: collection was processed twice by
> flush()

When do this error raised, and how to avoid it.

Another error that is produced is..

> Collection is not associated to the session.

I'm using hibernate 3 + seam 2 in my web apps.

Comment: i dont know which code produces the error. i have already huge pages together. :(

Comment: @EllieFabrero did you find any solution. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Actually the error is not occurring anymore in my part, what i did was to remove some of code from my component that heavily query from DB and put it in another component, in my case EntityList in seam.

Answer (score 2):

It is raised for example in cases where you are using one instance of EntityManager concurrently from multiple threads and you are unlucky enough to run to this problem. Without any context, it is hard to say why exactly it occurs in your case.

Comment: Usually the errors says that the property result count of the EntityList error reading. in my view.i will update my question for more info..thnx

Comment: I think you answers relates to the situation where i am now. i think that it is related to concurrent call to component..